# Is it possible to run Mercurial without ssl installed?

Tags: solaris, python, openssl, mercurial

I have a Solaris 5.8 machine without OpenSSL.  This platform is a real pain to get OpenSSL compiled for, and getting [Mordac](http://mordac.org/sub/mordac.jpg), our unix admin, to install the Solaris package isn't an option.

I'd like to run the Mercurial client, but this seems to require the Python `_ssl` module, which in turn requires OpenSSL or equivalent.  Is there a way to get Mercurial running without these libraries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not going to be possible without hacking Mercurial itself. We have a bunch of imports of the `_ssl` module, so those will certainly break without `_ssl`. You may put try/except ImportErrors around those imports and that might improve the situation a little bit. You could also try opening an issue in our bug tracker, but it's not really sure any of our crew will be interested in this somewhat outlandish scenario (of not having `_ssl`).